# Can we meet our pets in jannah if we make dua in duniyah?

Tags: dua, jannah, pets

I know this question is an widely asked question still I would like to know.
In jannah we will get everything that we will desire from Allah (SWT) even the haram things in duniyah like wine.

So is there any chance that we can meet our dead and lost pets in Jannah if we make dua??
because according to islam, all the creations except human and jinns will turn into dust at the day of judgement.

But if we make dua, is it possible to have our beloved pets living with us in Jannah for eternity.